# Java 8 - Convert LocalDate to OffsetDateTime

Tags: java, date, datetime, java-8, datetime-conversion

I like to know if it is possible to convert in Java 8 from LocalDate to OffsetDateTime.

For example assume that I have got this LocalDate:

```
1992-12-28
```

Then I would like to have it converted to this `OffsetDateTime`:

```
1992-12-28T00:00-03:00
```

Assume that we know the time zone, for example America/Santiago.

Comment: You’ll need at least `LocalDateTime`.

Comment: `LocalDate` has no time, but `OffsetDateTime` has, that is, needs one - so you must first specify which time of day it should get (kind of the point of having an `OffsetDateTime`, otherwise the offset has no meaning at all)

Comment: It's possible. You'd need to decide a time zone for that. Conventionslly one would convert the start of day, so your `OffsrtDateTime` will have hour of day set to 0. For example `yourLocalDate.atStartOfDay(ZoneId.of("Europe/Madrid")).toOffsetDateTime()`.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can try this..

```
OffsetDateTime o = OffsetDateTime.of(LocalDate.now(),LocalTime.NOON, ZoneOffset.UTC);
OffsetDateTime o1 = OffsetDateTime.of(LocalDateTime.now(), ZoneOffset.UTC);
```

Comment: `LocalTime.MIN` and `LocalTime.MIDNIGHT` = 00:00, `LocalTime.NOON` = 12:00, `LocalTime.MAX` = 23:59:59.

Answer (score 12):

The correct conversion is:

```
    ZoneId zone = ZoneId.of("Europe/Madrid");
    LocalDate date = LocalDate.of(2019, Month.JULY, 27);
    OffsetDateTime odt = date.atStartOfDay(zone)
            .toOffsetDateTime();
    System.out.println(odt);
```

Output:

> 2019-07-27T00:00+02:00

Substitute your desired time zone where I put `Europe/Madrid`.

Java knows about summer time (DST) and finds the correct offset for the time zone taking summer time into account. The `atStartOfDay` method that I call yields a `ZonedDateTime`, that is a date and time with time zone. It has a `toOffsetDateTime` method for converting to the `OffsetDateTime` that you asked for.

Answer (score 6):

There are many ways to convert `LocalDate` to `OffsetDateTime`. Some of them are listed below:

**1. Using [`LocalDate#atStartOfDay​(ZoneId zone)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/LocalDate.html#atStartOfDay(java.time.ZoneId)) => [`ZonedDateTime#toOffsetDateTime()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html#toOffsetDateTime()):**

```
LocalDate date = LocalDate.now();
ZoneOffset offset = ZoneOffset.UTC;
OffsetDateTime odt = date.atStartOfDay(offset).toOffsetDateTime();
```

This can also be used when you have `ZoneId` available e.g.

```
LocalDate date = LocalDate.now();

// You can use a custom ZoneId e.g. ZoneId.of("Europe/London")
ZoneId zoneId = ZoneId.systemDefault(); 

OffsetDateTime odt = date.atStartOfDay(zoneId).toOffsetDateTime();
```

**2. Using `LocalDate#atStartOfDay()` => [`LocalDateTime#atOffset​(ZoneOffset offset)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/LocalDateTime.html#atOffset(java.time.ZoneOffset)):**

```
LocalDate date = LocalDate.now();
ZoneOffset offset = ZoneOffset.UTC;
OffsetDateTime odt = date.atStartOfDay().atOffset(offset);
```

**3. Using `LocalDate#atTime(OffsetTime time)`:**

```
LocalDate date = LocalDate.now();
ZoneOffset offset = ZoneOffset.UTC;
OffsetDateTime odt = date.atTime(OffsetTime.of(LocalTime.MIDNIGHT, offset));
```

**4. Using [`OffsetDateTime#of​(LocalDate date, LocalTime time, ZoneOffset offset)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/OffsetDateTime.html#of(java.time.LocalDate,java.time.LocalTime,java.time.ZoneOffset)):**

```
LocalDate date = LocalDate.now();
ZoneOffset offset = ZoneOffset.UTC;
OffsetDateTime odt = OffsetDateTime.of(date, LocalTime.MIDNIGHT, offset);
```

---

**Notes:**

1. In all the solutions given above, replace the sample `ZoneOffset` as required e.g. `ZoneOffset offset =  ZoneOffset.of("+02:00")`.
2. In all the solutions given above, replace the sample `LocalDate` as required e.g. `LocalDate date =  LocalDate.of(2021, 3, 14)`.

Comment: Good. In the UTC case 2. is simpler than 1. and therefore preferred. We don’t often have an `OffsetTime`, so I don’t easily imagine a use for 3., but who knows?

Answer (score 2):

We do this all the time in our project. Especially to check if the a date is within a given date range. Here is how we do it.

```
public static OffsetDateTime getOffsetDateTime(LocalDate date, String zone) {
    return date.atStartOfDay(ZoneId.of(zone)).toOffsetDateTime();
}
```

The zone looks like `Australia/Melbourne` or `UTC`. You can alternatively use ZoneId directly if you have a handle to it. Setting it at a particular zone is important since OffsetDateTime will datetime with zone.

the invocation looks like below

```
String defaultZone = "Australia/Melbourne";
OffsetDateTime meetingStartDate = DateUtils.getOffsetDateTime(project.getCanStartDate(), defaultZone);
```

Comment: I find it cumbersome to user ZoneOffset and ZoneId for a system that is user facing. Using zone as String is quite intuitive to developers as well as users. Mapping addresses using Google Maps API also map it quite easily to zone strings. Hence I wanted to note the use of zone as String. The question also specified the same in its last sentence but none of the answers actually captured that.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you actually have `LocalDateTime`, you can do it like:

```
ZoneOffset zoneOffset = ZoneOffset.ofHours(2);
OffsetDateTime offsetDateTime = ldt.atOffset(zoneOffset);
```

With `ldt` being your `LocalDateTime` instance.